# Iam trying to bind the values back into the Form inputs, through the API return, but the label gets binded, but not the values into it

Tags: reactjs, select, drop-down-menu

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import "./SelectComponent.css";
import { useForm, useController, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
// import {newData} from "../newData"

// const Alpha = [
//   { value: 'avb', label: 'Toygfota' },
//   { value: 'Haconda', label: 'Hohvjnda' },
//   { value: 'Tesacasla', label: 'Teshvhjla' }
// ]

// const option=newData.map(function(eachcategory){
//   return
// })

var count = 0;
const FilterAccordionSelect = (props) => {

  // attributes
  count = count + 1;
  // const Brand = [
  //   { value: 'Toyota', label: 'Toyota' },
  //   { value: 'Honda', label: 'Honda' },
  //   { value: 'Tesla', label: 'Tesla' }
  // ]
  var attributes = props.attributes;

  const options = attributes.map(function (eachOption) {
    return {
      value: eachOption.id,
      label: eachOption.attribute,
    };
  });

  // const {input,setValue, placeholder } = props;
  const { input, placeholder, setSelectedValue, resetFieldd, searchData } = props;
  var reset = resetFieldd
  console.log("reset", reset);
  var name = input.field_name;
  const { register, control, handleSubmit,setValue } = useForm();
  // const {field}=useController({name:name,control});
  const { field } = useController({ name: input.field_display_name, control });
  // console.log("this is the uinput",input)
  // console.log("this is the name",name)

  // const handleSelectChange = (event) => {
  //   console.log(event);
  //   alert("klo")
  //   // setValue('mySelect', selectedOption.value);
  // };


  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({ value:"", label: "" });
  const handleOnchane = (option) => {
    console.log("select changed", option);
    var label = option.label;
    // field.onChange(label);
    console.log("onchange value", option);
    // setSelectedOption(option.value);
  };

  const handleOnchange = (selectedOption) => {
    console.log("Selected option:", selectedOption);
    console.log("this is the field", { field });
    // setValue(input.field_display_name, selectedOption.label);

  };

  useEffect(() => {
    for (const searchDataName in searchData) {
      // console.log(`key ${key}`,typeof(key));
      if (name == searchDataName) {
        // alert(name)
        options.map(function(item,index){
          console.log("item",item.value);
          if(item.value==searchData[searchDataName]){
            console.log("item",item);
            setSelectedOption({ value: item.value, label: item.label })

          }
        })
        console.log(`${searchDataName}:${name} ${searchData[searchDataName]}`);

      }

    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(()=>{
    
    setValue(name, selectedOption.value) 

  },[selectedOption])

  useEffect(() => {
    reset && setSelectedOption({ value: "", label: "" })
    console.log("reset inside useEffect", reset);


  }, [reset]);

  // const handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
  // setSelectedOption(selectedOption);
  //   console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  // };

  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={field.control}
      rules={options.length != 0 && { required: false }}
      render={({ field }) => (
        <Select
          {...field}
          options={options}
          //   isMulti={true}
          // value={selectedOption}

          // value={options.find((option) => option.label === field.label)}
          // value={options.find((option) => option.value === field.value)}
          // defaultValue={selectedOption}
          value={selectedOption}
          // inputValue={selectedOption.label}
          onChange={(selectedOption) => {
            setSelectedOption(selectedOption);
            field.onChange(selectedOption.value);
          }}
          // onChange={(selectedOption) => {
          // field.value=selectedOption.label
          // value=selectedOption
          // onChange={setSelectedOption}
          // field.onChange(selectedOption.value);
          // handleOnchange(selectedOption);
          // }}
          // value={{value:selectedOption.value, label:selectedOption.label}}
          // value={selectedOption}
          name={name}
          placeholder={placeholder}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default FilterAccordionSelect;

// 6e96ecdbed7ecf6cbf7f89c35ab91817ff99fbad
```

The thing is Iam not able to set the value to the binding, the Label gets binded, but the value is not stored, when i try to apply the form, with the binded value, the payload doesnt have the value.Here it is the select option, is there something related to the field.onchange.The thing is Iam not able to set the value to the binding, the Label gets binded, but the value is not stored, when i try to apply the form, with the binded value, the payload doesnt have the value.Here it is the select option, is there something related to the field.onchange